# Optical activity of (1r,3R,5S)-3,5-dimethyl-4-methylidenecyclohexan-1-ol

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, molecular-structure, optical-properties

Could anyone explain why compound L is not optically active?

[image: (1r,3R,5S)-3,5-dimethyl-4-methylidenecyclohexan-1-ol]

Comment: Draw the mirror image of the compound. Can you prove the mirrored version is different from the original?

Comment: For the same reason why meso-tartaric acid does not manifest chirality. Its mirror image can be identified with the original, even if it has 2 chiral centers.

Comment: Because it has a quite obvious plane of symmetry, period. That's enough of a justification, no matter what the chiral centers are trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

The given molecule,(1r,3R,5S)-3,5-dimethyl-4-methylenecyclohexanol , is optically inactive .This molecule has a plane of symmetry (as shown below) and, therefore, is achiral.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Imagine yourself cutting the molecule in half along the axis determined by the OH group and the double bond, perpendicular to the plane of the cyclohexane ring. Observe that the 2 halves match each other perfectly, in other words you found a plane of symmetry. For any molecule to be chiral, and thus be optically active, it must not have any plane of symmetry.